# How to run code when a static instance is initialized?

Tags: ios, swift, static, static-methods, swift5

I'm using this pattern:

```
open class CoreDataHub {

public static let sharedInstance = CoreDataHub()
  open class func getThing() -> String {
    return "hello world"
  }
  init() {
    sharedInstance.getThing()
  }

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Static member 'getThing' cannot be used on instance of type 'CoreDataHub'
```

My goal is to run some code...namely call getThing() when the sharedInstance is initialized. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Just call `getThing()` on `sharedInstance`'s `didSet`

Comment: Can you describe what pattern you are trying to use? I don't see what you are trying to achieve. Why are you ignoring the return value of `getThing`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting

```
Static member 'getThing' cannot be used on instance of type 'CoreDataHub'
```

because, you are called `getThing()` static method using `sharedInstance` object.

Use `CoreDataHub.getThing()` instead of `sharedInstance.getThing()`

```
public static let sharedInstance = CoreDataHub()
init() {
    let value = CoreDataHub.getThing()
    
}
```

Comment: I don't think so both proposals are same. I was updated this answer to pointed out why he's getting that error, and how to overcome that. Also my init is applicable for any  instance of `CodeDataHub` by using public init.

Comment: Yep. I just suggested that, he can fix that error by calling `CoreDataHub.getThing()` instead of `sharedInstance.getThing()`.